# "Theme info" checkbox not showing on non-admin pages

Tags: theming

I'm using the Theme Developer module. When I enable it, the `Theme info` checkbox shows up in the admin pages, but it doesn't show on the non-admin pages (e.g. Home page). There aren't any JS errors from the console. What could I be missing to make it appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, someone wrote a module in the project to unset the default Drupal JavaScripts. Just had to remove that code to make everything work the way they should.